# Problem in VBA userforms - resolution totally changed

Tags: excel, vba

I built an excel file with several userforms in VBA, which contain buttons (form controls). Usually i work with dock-station to connect my laptop to big screen (im my office). sometimes i open the file with no docking station (only laptop). 
I opened today the file, and found out that the resolution is totally changed, the user forms become so big and in all buttons the text inside are wrapped to right. 
Please your support to know How can i correct the problem?

thanks

[image]

Comment: please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Do you know if these are `form control` or `active x` buttons? Also, is this on a sheet or form?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue caused by the File being open while your native screen resolution changes (and *possibly* only when this also changes the Aspect Ratio) - the most common reason for that being connecting or disconnecting a Laptop to/from an external screen (in this case, via your Docking Station)

There are 2 forms this issue takes:  either the Button stays the same size, and but the contents (text, images, etc) are scaled up/down while anchored in the top-left - which is what has happened here - or the contents stay the same size, but the button itself gets larger/smaller until it either covers the whole sheet or is too small to click.

In my experience, the only way to fix the buttons is adjust them, and force Excel to redraw the shape instead of "remembering" what it should look like.  You *can* do this manually, <s>but I will try to track down some code to "reset" buttons for you.</s> *here is some code to do things for you.*

(For a UserForm, you **may** just be able to call `Me.Repaint` to force a redraw without needing to bother with the resizing - but I haven't tested that as I can never get this issue to happen on-demand >_<)

### UserForm Button Fix

```vb
Sub FixButtonFormat(ByRef Button As Control)
    Dim Top As Double, Left As Double, Width As Double, Height As Double, FontName As String, FontSize As Double

    Top = Button.Top
    Left = Button.Left
    Width = Button.Width
    Height = Button.Height
    FontName = Button.Object.Font.Name
    FontSize = Button.Object.Font.Size

    'Scale Button up slightly
    Button.Top = Top - 1
    Button.Left = Left + 1
    Button.Width = Width - 2
    Button.Height = Height + 2
    Button.Object.Font.Size = FontSize + 1

    DoEvents
    UserForm1.Repaint
    DoEvents

    'Reset button to original size
    Button.Top = Top
    Button.Left = Left
    Button.Width = Width
    Button.Height = Height
    Button.Object.Font.Name = FontName
    Button.Object.Font.Size = FontSize
End Sub
```

### Worksheet Button Fix

```vb
Sub FixButtonFormat(ByRef Button As Shape)
    If Button.Type <> msoFormControl And Button.Type <> msoOLEControlObject Then Exit Sub
    Dim Top As Double, Left As Double, Width As Double, Height As Double, FontName As String, FontSize As Double
    Dim Screen As Boolean
    Screen = Application.ScreenUpdating

    Top = Button.Top
    Left = Button.Left
    Width = Button.Width
    Height = Button.Height
    If Button.Type = msoFormControl Then 'Form Control
        FontName = Button.OLEFormat.Object.Font.Name
        FontSize = Button.OLEFormat.Object.Font.Size
    ElseIf Button.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then 'ActiveX Control
        FontName = Button.DrawingObject.Object.Font.Name
        FontSize = Button.DrawingObject.Object.Font.Size
    End If

    'Scale Button up slightly
    Button.Top = Top - 1
    Button.Left = Left + 1
    Button.Width = Width - 2
    Button.Height = Height + 2
    If Button.Type = msoFormControl Then 'Form Control
        Button.OLEFormat.Object.Font.Size = FontSize + 1
    ElseIf Button.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then 'ActiveX Control
        Button.DrawingObject.Object.Font.Size = FontSize + 1
    End If

    If Not Screen Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        DoEvents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Else
        DoEvents
    End If

    'Reset button to original size
    Button.Top = Top
    Button.Left = Left
    Button.Width = Width
    Button.Height = Height
    If Button.Type = msoFormControl Then 'Form Control
        Button.OLEFormat.Object.Font.Name = FontName
        Button.OLEFormat.Object.Font.Size = FontSize
    ElseIf Button.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then 'ActiveX Control
        Button.DrawingObject.Object.Font.Size = FontSize
        Button.DrawingObject.Object.Font.Name = FontName
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In Office365, I had the same issue (I must have detached my laptop from a docking station while a VBA form was showing on an external monitor) where everything became supersized.

I went into the code and opened up the form object to manually resize everything - when I clicked the bottom right corner of the UserForm rectangle to resize it, all the controls on the form instantly corrected themselves back down to proper size to match to my current screen resolution, and snapped back to the upper left of the form. All I had to do was reduce the UserForm to match the corrected controls.